# How do I parse msgid and msgstr out of the .po file

Tags: c#, mono

From this link http://www.mono-project.com/archived/internationalization/

I've coding to read .po file as Text file like the normal code to open file. (Import Mono.Unix already.)

```
 if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);        
            string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            string result = Path.GetFileName(filename);                

            string tryString = Catalog.GetString(richTextBox1.Text);
            richTextBox1.Text = tryString;

        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
```

From the code, it's occur exception.(And I know it'll be like that.) I want to parse only msgid and msgstr(Source Text and Translation?) as the normal text in C# But I have no idea to do next with code. Can someone help me? Thank you.